# Accessing the attributes of a specific instance of a user control within a page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, server-side, client-side

I'm attempting to find a way to differentiate between instances of user controls (.ascx) on the same page. These user controls all have their own associated controls within the page which they need to interact with.

For this particular "provider lookup" tool I need to be able to adjust the value of textboxes on the page which do not all have the same ID.

Hopefully the below will show what I mean.

HTML of my .aspx page, where I include three different instances of the user control:

```
<uc4:providerlookup ID="ProviderLookupReferring" runat="server" allowunassigned="true" associatedtextbox="ReferringProviderNameTextBox"/>
<uc4:providerlookup ID="ProviderLookupPrimary" runat="server" allowunassigned="false" associatedtextbox="PrimaryProviderNameTextBox"/>
<uc4:providerlookup ID="ProviderLookupSecondary" runat="server" allowunassigned="false" associatedtextbox="SecondaryProviderNameTextBox"/>
```

Javascript example within the user control (providerlookup.ascx):

```
    unassignedProviderSelection() 
{

        if (document.getElementById("DetailContentPlaceHolder_ReferringProviderNameTextBox") != null) 
            {
                document.getElementById("ReferringProviderNameTextBox").value = "Blah blah blah";
            }
    }
```

HTML within the user control (providerlookup.ascx):

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonUnassignedProvider" runat="server" text="Unassigned"
    onclientclick="unassignedProviderSelection(); return false;"
    CausesValidation="False"  Width="117px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

So, what I'm doing here is providing a button within that user control called "ButtonUnassignedProvider" which I want to use to modify the contents of a textbox within the .aspx page that I include the user control in.

The problem is that I don't know the id of the textbox: I want to do this in a generic way by allowing you to set a custom attribute of the user control when you declare an instance in your .aspx page.

I didn't write the original user control: it's not going anywhere and I need to try to enhance it with this new functionality. The way I'm trying to do it may not be the best way though...

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm really hoping to do this client-side in the javascript code. I know there may be server side solutions and I would love to see those too, but client side is my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FindControl` to navigate up the control tree and then get the correct `ClientID`. It would look something like this on the aspx page where the UserControl is located.

```
document.getElementById("<%= ProviderLookupReferring.FindControl("ButtonUnassignedProvider").ClientID %>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a chance to speak with a more experience Web developer this morning and he suggested building my Javascript on the server side and then adding an onclientclick event to the Unassigned button. This seems to work so I think that's what I'll do.